# Parent not adjusting width relative to child element

Tags: html, css

In Safari, when using the dynamic `vw` CSS unit for width and height, the parent element (without specified dimensions) will not adjust itself to the child element's width dimensions. Below is a fiddle and some screen shots:

http://jsfiddle.net/gby3N/

[image: In Chrome]

[image: In Safari]

Any ideas or workarounds to this issue?

Comment: In my i-Mac, it is working fine. Because Chrome and Safari both have the same rendering engine. It shouldnt show this behavior.

Comment: Reproduced in Safari 6.1.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same behaviour in Safari 7.0.4 and the only explanation I can come up with is that it's a Safari bug. Which is strange because I could only find people talking about iOS Safari having issues - nothing about desktop Safari.

Luckily the "buggyfill" that fixes iOS Safari's handling of viewport units, at https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill, seems to work here as well. I just had to add

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill/master/viewport-units-buggyfill.js"></script>
<script>window.viewportUnitsBuggyfill.init(true);</script>
```

to get `parent` to stretch to fit `child` in Safari. Note that I used `init(true)` instead of just `init()`, which checks for an iOS user agent.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gby3N/2/

You also might have the option of simply adding `min-width: 12vw;` to the parent element. (`12vw` is the width of the child element.)